# Unable to write file into folder

Tags: laravel, putty, filezilla

hello i am still new to make localhost project into putty server and i also use fileZilla.

my upload image function is working fine in localhost but when i tried it in the server. the error happened like this
[image: fileException]

and here is my controller

```
public function uploadPic(Request $request)
{
    $rules = ['image' => 'required|image|max:1024*1024*1'];

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect('profile')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $file->move(public_path("profile-image/"), $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $thisUser = \Auth::id();

        $result = User::where('id','=',$thisUser)->update(['path_gambar'  => $file->getClientOriginalName()]);
    }
    return redirect('profile');
}
```

and here is the view blade

```
<form class="form-group-sm" action="{{ url('/upload-image') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="token" type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <div>
                    <input type="file" class="btn" name="image" id="file">
                </div>
             <span class="help-block">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
             </span>
                <div style="text-align: inherit">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group-sm" value="upload" name="Submit">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: You have not set the permissions on that folder correctly for Laravel to access it. Do you have SSH access to your server?

Comment: @James i don't use SSH key, but it works in the localhost hmm

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is either a file system permission error or bad file path error.

The reason this works on your local machine is because your local system is more permissive -- your user has sufficient permissions to write the file or the system helps you resolve the bad path to a good one. This is likely because you are using an operating system, such as Windows, that does not enforce permissions the same way your *nix server does.

Let's look at these issues

- Wrongly formatted file path
- Non-existent file path
- Insufficient permissions

**Path**

Look at your path. The double slash is a bad thing.

> /var/www/html/gracia/public//profile-image

There may be some underlying issues but a quick fix to test is to use [realpath()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

```php
$file->move(realpath(public_path("profile-image/")), $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Now you must confirm that the directory actually exists on your server. SSH (putty) into the system and run:

```sh
ls -l /var/www/html/gracia/public
```

Or FTP in and navigate to the path.

The `profile-image` directory must be there.

**Permission**

SSH (putty) into the system and run:

```sh
ls -l /var/www/html/gracia/public
```

Output (example):

```sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 gracia users 4096 Jun 19 12:27 profile-image
```

These permissions mean that only the user `gracia` can write to the directory. It is likely that the web server does not run as this user, so you must change the permissions so that the directory is accessible to that user.

Here is how to make the directory write-able for all users.

```sh
chmod -R 777 public-image/
```

Output (example):

```sh
drwxrwxrwx 2 gracia users 4096 Jun 19 12:27 profile-image
```